# Running python code in background

Tags: python, linux, background, ssh

I need to run a python code that takes several hours and my computer disconnects from the ssh after a certain amount of inactive time.

I have tried python  test.py > output.txt & but my output file is empty. However, the python code "test" is still running after I log off and log back in to the ssh. I also tried python -u test.py > output.txt &  which does write to the output.txt but it does not continue after the ssh connection is lost.

I am very new to Linux so I do not know very many commands. I need the simplest/easiest to understand method. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `screen`, as Robin Krahl recommended, or you can just run your command with nohup, which suppresses the `SIGHUP` (hangup) signal from your SSH session disconnecting.

`nohup "python -u test.py > output.txt" &`

Answer (score 1):

[`screen`](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen) is the tool you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) is what you want. [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) is newer? tool that does the same thing, and [byobu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byobu_%28software%29) is an easy-to-use wrapper for both.